# Get the docker image size from Jfrog Artifactory

Tags: docker, rest, artifactory

I have docker images stored in jFrog artifactory and I need to get the size of those docker images without pulling it. I tried to figure out if there is any direct REST API provided by jFrog but couldn’t find any.

I also tried one solution by doing a curl request to fetch all the docker layers and to sum all the layers. But I’m looking if there is any feasible solution other than the above?

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use [**`regclient`**](https://github.com/regclient/regclient#regclient).

It does allow to inspect images *without pulling the layers*, allowing quick access to the image manifest and configuration.

And the manifest include the size of the image.
Start with the [`regctl manifest` command](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/blob/main/docs/regctl.md#manifest-commands):

```
regctl manifest get <yourJFrogName>/<yourImageName>:<tag>
```

Or:

```
regctl image inspect --format '{{jsonPretty .}}' <yourJFrogName>/<yourImageName>:<tag>
```

It should include the [total size](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/blob/243cb6accfb9987656b85f54f161a10d350c2acb/types/manifest/oci1.go#L215-L219):

```bash
$ regctl manifest get localhost:5000/artifact:demo
Name:        localhost:5000/artifact:demo
MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
Digest:      sha256:36484d44383fc9ffd34be11da4a617a96cb06b912c98114bfdb6ad2dddd443e2
Annotations: 
  demo:      true
  format:    oci
Total Size:  64B
```

Comment: Thanks a lot von, It worked as expected but the only problem is that in the artifactory it is giving us the compressed size but not the original

Comment: @ManisaiBashetty Even using the Artifactory API, as in [Gajapathi Kimidi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17812607/gajapathi-kimidi)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73982984/6309)?

Answer (score 0):

JFrog provides a get artifact details [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FileInfo) where you can get the file size of the image with below REST API.

```
curl -u admin -X GET http://localhost:8082/artifactory/api/storage/docker-local/nginx/latest/manifest.json -H "Content-type: application/json"
```

This will give the following output along with the size.

```
{
  "repo" : "docker-local",
  "path" : "/nginx/latest/manifest.json",
  ----------
  "downloadUri" : "https://localhost:8082/artifactory/docker-local/nginx/latest/manifest.json",
  "mimeType" : "application/json",
  "size" : "1570",
  "checksums" : {
    "sha1" : "cc357b563ce443aa8270eb34e6755458a1a46869",
    --------
  },
  "originalChecksums" : {
    "sha256" : "89020cd33be2767f3f894484b8dd77bc2e5a1ccc864350b92c53262213257dfc"
  },
  "uri" : "https://localhost:8082/artifactory/api/storage/docker-local/nginx/latest/manifest.json"
}
```

Comment: This fetches the size of the manifest, not the whole image.